# Titan-Cassandra graph not (immediately) saved on commit?

Tags: gremlin, titan, tinkerpop

I am working with Titan Server (using Cassandra) v0.3.1 on Windows 7 and seeing some inconsistent behavior around writes to the graph.  For some reason, new nodes seem to "disappear" after committing a transaction.  I'm thinking there is some sort of cache/delayed write involved, but am not sure what Titan is doing under the hood.

Do you have any ideas as to why nodes seem to disappear on commit?

--

Here is a sequence of commands run in the Gremlin shell:

```
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open("cassandra.local")
==>titangraph[cassandrathrift:127.0.0.1]
```

Shows the two nodes I have added to the graph so far:

```
gremlin> g.V
==>v[280096]
==>v[280100]
```

Now add a node:

```
gremlin> g.addVertex()
==>v[360004]
```

New node appears in graph:

```
gremlin> g.V
==>v[280096]
==>v[280100]
==>v[360004]
```

Now, commit transaction:

```
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
```

...and the new node is gone:

```
gremlin> g.V
==>v[280096]
==>v[280100]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution boiled down to a configuration issue.  I had modified `cassandra.yaml` to use windows-formatted filepaths e.g. `c:/titan-all-0.3.1/cassandra/data`, but it seems that that format confused java/cassandra.

I just restored the original `cassandra.yaml` file (it's smart enough to figure out that `/tmp` is `c:/tmp`) and everything seems to be working fine now.